# Rich Notification extension not called in ios13

Tags: swift, iphone, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, ios13

The normal notification pops up when I sending this payload from the server. Extension not called for rich notification.

**Using Firebase service**

1) Registered category in AppDelegate
2) Added "mutable_content = true" in payload
3) tried category name in payload
4) selected extension as the target for app debugging
5) added allow arbitrary load true in info.plist for the extension.
  help me !!

**Notification payload:**

```
{
        "to": "FCM token",

               "mutable_content": true,
          "notification":
            {
          "title":"Offers", 
          "body":"Buy one Get One",
          "badge":1,
          "sound":"default"

          },
        "data": {
        "attachment-url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/99/SOME_LIKE_IT_HOT_TITLE.jpg/800px-SOME_LIKE_IT_HOT_TITLE.jpg"
      }
    }
```

**Custom class**

```
import UserNotifications

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

   private var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
      private var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

        defer {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent ?? request.content)
        }

        guard let attachment = request.attachment else { return }

        bestAttemptContent?.attachments = [attachment]

    }


    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
        // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }

}


extension UNNotificationRequest {
    var attachment: UNNotificationAttachment? {
        guard let attachmentURL = content.userInfo["attachment-url"] as? String, let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: attachmentURL)!) else {
            return nil
        }
        return try? UNNotificationAttachment(data: imageData, options: nil)
    }
}

extension UNNotificationAttachment {

    convenience init(data: Data, options: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) throws {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let temporaryFolderName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
        let temporaryFolderURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(temporaryFolderName, isDirectory: true)

        try fileManager.createDirectory(at: temporaryFolderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        let imageFileIdentifier = UUID().uuidString + ".png"
        let fileURL = temporaryFolderURL.appendingPathComponent(imageFileIdentifier)
        try data.write(to: fileURL)
        try self.init(identifier: imageFileIdentifier, url: fileURL, options: options)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Payload structure should be like

```
{
    "aps":{
        "alert":{
            "title":"Push Pizza Co.",
            "body":"Your pizza is  almost ready!"
        },
        "badge”:1,
        "sound":"default",
        "category":"catName",
        "mutable-content":1
    },
    "attachment-url": "https://www.example.com/image_url"

}
```

Comment: if I try with `aps` notification is not received

Answer (score 0):

You should customize your message for iOS. From the Firebase docs:

```
{
  "message":{
    "token" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "This is an FCM notification that displays an image.!",
      "title" : "FCM Notification",
     },
     "apns": {
         "payload": {
             "aps": {
                 "mutable-content": 1
             }
         },
         "fcm_options": {
             "image": "url-to-image"
         }
       }
   }
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/send-image

Answer (score 0):

Firebase mutates the push payload if the payload contains any platform specific keys in order push payload to work for both Android and iOS platforms. Since **mutable-content** is an iOS specific key, we need to add it in **"aps"** payload with key name **"mutable_content"**.

This is our payload which we send to the FCM:

```
"notification" => [
   "title" => $title,
   "body" =>  $body['content'],
   'sound' => 'default',
   'badge' => 1,
],
"aps" => [
    "mutable_content" => 1
]
```

This will trigger your **NotificationService** extension.

If you also want to work with **NotificationContent** extension and **category** key in the **aps** payload is not working for you; then you can add the category identifier to the payload in **NotificationService** extension's ***didReceive*** method as shown below:

```
override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest,
         withContentHandler contentHandler:
         @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler
    bestAttemptContent = request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent
    if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
        bestAttemptContent.categoryIdentifier = {YOUR_NOTIFICATION_CATEGORY}
        contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
    }
}
```